# Reading in Text File

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to read in a text file using Haskell, but based on my limited and little knowledge of the language, I'm have a bit of trouble an would like some help.

I have a text file with 1000+ random words, and would like to read in the text file
I know that I have to

```
import System.IO
```

and maybe

```
import Data.List
```

and I have something like this:

```
main = do 
       let list = []
       handle <- openFile "words.txt" ReadMode
       contents <- hGetContents handle
```

but I don't know much more to proceed.
Any help would be great. I've been stuck for a while now and have a deadline coming soon. Thank you!

Comment: It'd be better to use the `readFile` function, you won't have to worry about file mode or handles.  After reading it like `contents <- readFile "words.txt"`, you'll want to perform a transformation like `let allLines = lines contents`, then you could print it out like `print $ take 5 all_lines`

Comment: This is almost completely identical (including the strange `let list = []` line) to a question asked a few days ago, but I can't find it now. The previous question included some goals for what to be done with the data (sort the list of words).

Comment: see here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867723/haskell-file-reading

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned in the comments, the simplest way to do this is to use the `readFile` function. `readFile` is actually part of prelude (the base library), so you don't have to import anything.

`contents <- readFile "words.txt"` will lazily load the entire file into the string `contents`. Then, you can do various string processing to parse the file as you want. The function `lines` (included by default as well) will split the `contents` into a list of strings, splitting it on line breaks. The function `words` will split `contents` into a list of strings, splitting it on whitespace.

For more advanced methods, you can look into the System.IO library documention on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/System-IO.html). The documentation provided on Hackage tends to be clear and a really useful resource.

Keep up with Haskell! It's worth it.