# How t to count the number of words in a file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am following this book.
http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html

I am completly stuck on how to count the number of words in a file. On my way of trying to solve this I also notices something interesting.

```
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = show (length (input)) ++ "\n"
```

I noticed that without the "\n" character I instead get a percentage sign appended at the end of the number.

```
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = show (length (input))
```

So I have 2 questions why do I get the percentage sign if I don't append the "\n"
character and how do I count all the words in a file? This is so much more complicated than any interpreted language I have learned. But I am loving the challenge.

In my text file I deleted all city's except for one.
Below is the contents of my txt file

```
Teignmouth, England
```

Comment: The percentage sign is not related to Haskell, it's coming from the shell: [Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27238564/770830).

Comment: I think it would help you to quote the exercise's problem statement in its entirety, along with the original source file it's asking you to modify.

Comment: This is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867723/haskell-file-reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your shell is actually appending a `%` because the output of your program doesn't end with a newline ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol)). The POSIX standard defines a "line" as something that ends with a `\n` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)).
2. The function [`words`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:words) is what you're looking for:

```
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = (show $ length $ words input) ++ "\n"
```

Note that the `$` operator allows for reduction of parentheses. This code is equivalent:

```
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = (show (length (words input))) ++ "\n"
```